# Multi node tree picker Umbraco 7.2.1 unable to sort

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Has anyone ran into this problem, on Umbraco 7.2.1, I'm unable to sort any nodes once seleted[image]

There is no JavaScript errors and have looked at Umbraco.controller.js and added breakpoints in Chrome. The js file get hit when adding or removing items, but when trying to sort nothing.

In Umbraco 7.3.4, this feature works OK.

Is this a bug in 7.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is indeed a bug in 7.2.X. I've experienced issues with sorting as a whole on the 7.2 platform.

In the link below, you'll see there has been issues with sorting in 7.1 as well.

http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4633